# How to keep a page on a fake loading state

Tags: javascript, html, browser, loading

How do I keep the page on a fake loading state via javascript?

I have a page that I set to $('body').hide() until it finishes loading a AJAX request, after that the page is set to $('body').show(). In the meantime (about 2 seconds) the page stays blank and the browser icon stops loading, then it shows the content or redirect to another page (according to the returned AJAX variables).

There's any way to make the browser stay on a loading state even it isn't loading anything? Just to seems like it's still loading stuff.

I've already tried to create something like:

```
while(page_loading())
    var l = 1;
```

But then the browser crashes. How can I force this "fake" state?

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to mention before: I want to keep the page blank as usual without any loading gif or anything like that but forcing the browser to be on a loading state. When the browser is loading a page there's an loading icon that keeps appearing on the browser tab or a message on statusbar. I know these particular states can't be change on directly with javascript so I thought that there's a way to keep the browser on this loading state using some infinite looping HTML request, or something like that. If I set "cursor: wait" the browser tab still changes to a "finish state".

Comment: `html, body { cursor: wait; }`

Comment: You're either incredibly misguided, or up to no good.

Comment: Misguided? I just want to keep the browser on a busy state while ajax is still executing.

Comment: Sure; you're in the browser, you shouldn't worry about the state of the chrome. What benefit is it to the user (who controls the browser) that this page "appears" to be legitimately loading longing than it is? The answer is you really can't *cause* a false loading state *in the browser* and there is no `sleep()` in Javascript. You can *simulate* a loading state (as noted in the two answers), though. If you want the page to complete loading, block the page it's loading from finishing and do the work on the server.

Comment: Here's a demo in PHP using `sleep(5)`, which pauses execution by five seconds: https://ignite.io/code/51309ed9ec221ead29000001 Click the play button on the top, left. This is how long polling in PHP works, by the way, which is what Facebook defaults to if web sockets are not available for true comet/push functionality in loading background updates.

Comment: It's *possible*... *maybe*... If you use an `iframe` for the loading, or a `script` block (e.g., using `src="polling.php"`) polling a PHP-controlled page at the bottom that calls a `sleep()` script (`script src="..."` blocks load), this will block the page from reaching load state. Then use the parent for the AJAX call (`script` I'm not entirely sure if this will work) and then signal the *server* that the `iframe` or `script` tag can complete and end the `sleep`. That could possibly work, but only because it's got the server blocking and the `iframe` or `script` acts as more or less a wedge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loading animation as *yourdeveloperfriend* suggests is probably the way to go. However, you *can* approximate a page loading using `cursor: wait`:

```
html,
body {
    cursor: wait;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #555;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

setTimeout(function unwait() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    document.body.innerHTML = 'Loaded.';
}, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8cxA7/

Obviously, this is just a demo. The tab favicon should be left alone, in my opinion, since some browsers will cache what they first see and hold onto that favicon for dear life.

Comment: Thanks, the "cursor: wait" was the closest think that I've found to the "busy state". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to handle this is to create a loading gif that appears and disappears. You can [create your own gif](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and download it. Then when the page starts loading: `$("#mygif").show();` and when it's done, `$("#mygif").hide();`